# Is there a way to ignore disk provisioning changes on vsphere datastore side in terraform?

Tags: terraform, vsphere, vcenter

I am currently trying to work around a problem a customer has with his vcenter storage configuration. We create VMs with a terraform module and initially pull the values from "eagerly_scrub" and "thin_provisioned" from the vsphere template as datasource, as it is best practice.
Currently we have the problem that the customer has a new datastore cluster with intransparent/inconsistent vmotion/DRS settings in place. So an automatic vmotion migration can cause the disk to jump from "thick provisioned, eagerly zeroed" to "thin provisioned" and I am not able to make terraform ignore that change.
To make it work at all we had to hardcode the new expected values into the module like:

```
disk {
   label            = "disk0"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.small.disks.0.size
    eagerly_scrub    = true
    thin_provisioned = false
  }
```

These machines are created as planned but even with a ignore_changes lifecycle for the disk setting in place

```
lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = [disk]
}
```

a newly migrated and thin provisioned VM would break the next terraform plan with `eagerly_scrub and thin_provisioned cannot both be set to true`
Which I totally get but I think I need terraform to totally ignore all changes in the underlying provisioning settings of the disk. Is this even possible?
We are running `Terraform v0.12.13 and provider.vsphere v1.13.0`
literally any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the terraform vsphere provider code I think I can pretty much close my own question.
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/blob/1c7a063bc8fc32f53ad2d237831bac73c2ee7692/vsphere/internal/virtualdevice/virtual_machine_disk_subresource.go#L1329

Looks like it is impossible